# npm install -g vue-cli -> coffeescript moved

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, dependencies, vue-cli

I've tried to install it using many `nodejs` / `npm` versions, on many different hosts, including a docker image:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM node:slim
 ---> c4e99b1ed64f
Step 2/4 : RUN npm i -g vue-cli
 ---> Running in 5a2bc7ff05ae
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has
moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
^C
```

And I keep getting this error every time.
This is the official issue thread: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/655
As you can see, there is not much info there. All they say is that it will be fixed in version `2.9.2`, while I'm trying to install `2.9.3`..

Has anyone else encountered this error? Have you dealt with it?

Comment: its not an error. its a deprecation warning, and it doesnt have any effect.
(it says `coffee-script` has moved to `coffeescript` on npm)

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem. After understanding it, looking at the prompt, it was just a warning that CoffeeScript moved to "coffeescript" is normal.